# Atributo readonly en widget de una forma Django

Tags: django, formularios, django-forms

Buen dia, he tenido un problema queriendo hacer que solo unos fields de un formulario sean solo lectura este es mi codigo de la forma:

```
class ReporteForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = reporte_fallo

    fields=[
        'num_inventario',
        'serie',
        'falla',
        'descripcion',
        'area',
    ]

    labels = {
        'num_inventario' : 'Número de inventario',
        'serie' : 'Serie',
        'falla' : 'Falla del equipo',
        'descripcion' : 'Descripción del equipo',
        'area' : 'Area del problema',
    }
    widget={
        'num_inventario': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
        'serie': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
        'falla': forms.TextInput(),
        'descripcion':forms.TextInput(),
        'area': forms.Select(),
    }
```

Y este es el codigo de la vista que lo manda a llamar

```
class reporteupdate(UpdateView):
model = reporte_fallo
form_class = ReporteForm
template_name = 'formulario/jefe_asignar.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('formulario:reporte_listar_jefe')
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

Comment: que version de Django usas

Comment: te sugiero que lo hagas de la siguiente forma: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos puedes hacerlo de diferentes formas:

```
'serie': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'true'}),
```

O de esta otra forma:

```
serie = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
```

Te sugiero revisar la siguiente respuesta:

[Disable input django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot)

Espero te sirva..!!